# Go to check EC2 environment? Or DNS domain name?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, go

I want to see if the program is being run in EC2 or not.

One way is to run `hostname -d` in EC2 to get the `DNS domain name`.

How do I get this DNS domain name in Go.

I looked at the `net` package using http://golang.org/pkg/net/#LookupNS

But I need to pass an argument.

How do I check if it's in EC2 or not?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain why you are doing this though?

Comment: Some of the things I can imagine you doing with this (like 'dev mode' vs. 'prod mode' switches) might be better accomplished with configuration that you pass in a file or environment variables or command-line flags when starting the program, rather than by detecting where it's being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if there is an interface with a specific name with this function:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "strings"
)

func trace(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf(fmt, args...)
}

func HasAddrWithName(name string) (bool, error) {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    for _, iface := range ifaces {
        addrs, err := iface.Addrs()
        if err != nil {
            trace("%s", err)
            continue
        }
        for _, addr := range addrs {
            ipaddr, _, err := net.ParseCIDR(addr.String())
            if err != nil {
                trace("%s", err)
                continue
            }
            hosts, err := net.LookupAddr(ipaddr.String())
            if err != nil {
                trace("%s", err)
                continue
            }
            for idx, h := range hosts {
                trace("%d: %s\n", idx, h)
                if strings.Contains(h, name) {
                    return true, nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false, nil
}

func main() {
    hasAddr, err := HasAddrWithName(".ec2.internal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if hasAddr {
        log.Println("inside ec2")
        return
    }

    log.Println("Not inside ec2")
}
```

The function will try to find all the interface an resolve the ip to a dns name. if the name contains the specific string returns true.

Answer (score 1):

The right way, IMO, is to try and hit the metadata API at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data` from the machine itself. The worrisome part is that you feel the need to know this in code. I am not quite sure what the use case for this is but it seems to me that there ought to be a way for you to know this outside of your code.

Nevertheless:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    /* if you just need the hostname */
    name, _ := os.Hostname()
    fmt.Println(name)

    /* if you must hit the EC2 metadata API */
    client := http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Duration(2 * time.Second),
    }

    resp, err := client.Get("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Probably not on EC2")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```